# Linkedin: How to make api calls using access token?

Tags: zend-framework, oauth, linkedin-api, access-token

I am storing the linkedin access token in database. This is the token that is stored in my database:

```
oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_token_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_expires_in=5183998&oauth_authorization_expires_in=5183998
```

I want to retrieve the linkedin connections using this access token. I am trying to make a call like this:

```
        $a = new Zend_Oauth_Token_Access();
        $client = $a->getHttpClient( array( 
                        'siteUrl' => LIN_SITE_URL,
                        'callbackUrl' => LIN_SITE_CALLBACK_URL,
                        'requestTokenUrl' => LIN_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL,
                        'userAuthorizationUrl' => LIN_USER_AUTHORIZATION_URL,
                        'accessTokenUrl' => LIN_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL,
                        'consumerKey' => LIN_CONSUMER_KEY,
                        'consumerSecret' => LIN_CONSUMER_SECRET
                    ) );

        $client->setUri('http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url)');   
        $client->setParameterGet('token',$linToken);
        $client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::GET);
        $response = $client->request();

        $content =  $response->getBody();
        $data = json_decode(Zend_Json::fromXml($content, false));   
        print_r($data); echo "<br/>";
```

The error i am getting here is:

```
stdClass Object ( [error] => stdClass Object ( [status] => 404 [timestamp] => 1349429996351 [request-id] => 8U8A1UNF1V [error-code] => 0 [message] => Could not find person based on: ~ ) )
```

Is this the correct way to make a call or am i doing something wrong here. I am using zend framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by passing the outh_token and outh_token_secret as an array to the setParams() of Zend_Oauth_Token_Access as below:

```
$a = new Zend_Oauth_Token_Access;
 $a->setParams(array(
  'oauth_token' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'oauth_token_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
 ));
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code example I don't see where you're setting the access token and secret. I just see that you're instantiating the $a variable:

```
$a = new Zend_Oauth_Token_Access();
```

Are you retrieving the access token and secret from you database then setting it to the $a variable? Something like this:

```
   $a->setToken($row['token'])
     ->setTokenSecret($row['secret']);
```

By the way, this is a good reference for using Zend and LinkedIn: http://www.contentwithstyle.co.uk/content/linkedin-and-zendoauth/

Comment: In the db i am storing the whole string i get back as access token. Here is what i get back below:

oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_token_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_expires_in=5183998&oauth_authorization_expires_in=5183998

I access the above from db. I am not setting the token and token secret anywhere. I am wondering if its the right way to store the access token in the db. How do others store? Should i store the oauth_token and oauth_token_secret separately in the db ?